# Store SQL query in database table (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata

Possibly my question is really stupid and I do not see the obvious solution ;-)

I want to store a SQL query within a table in my database (Teradata). I want to SELECT that query using Python and then replace certain strings which I use as parameters in the query.

Let's say the SQL I want to store looks like this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, CASE 
WHEN blah = 'teststring'...#param1#...
```

I try to store this statement within the database as a string using ''. That means in my INSERT statement, the query looks like 'SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, CASE WHEN blah = 'teststring'...#param1#...'

However, I get an error that the insert failed because of the ' ' around my teststring? So my question is: how can I avoid/circumvent this error, as I need to insert strings within the 'string query'.

Your help is highly appreciated :-)

Many thanks
FJ

Comment: You need to double the quotes: `'SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, CASE WHEN blah = ''teststring''...#param1#...'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

With ' \ ' before and after the ".

```
'SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, CASE WHEN blah = \"teststring\"...#param1#...'
```

Comment: There are no double quotes in the OP's example, and to escape the single quotes, you use another single quote.

Comment: Many thanks, '\'myString\'' works like charm...obvious way to do it...just could not think of this easy solution, great and super quick support from you guys! :D